# Align IconButton with Text in a line

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I need to put IconButtons together with plain text in one single text. However, it didn't show as I expected. Here is what I did:

JS(ReactJS):

```js
<div>
  <span>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <IconButton className="editBtn" size="small">
      <EditIcon style={{ fontSize: 25 }} />
    </IconButton>

    <IconButton className="deleteBtn" size="small">
      <DeleteIcon style={{ fontSize: 25 }} />
    </IconButton>
  </span>

  <p>Article</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.deleteBtn {
    padding: 3vw !important;
    color: #e71f1f !important;
    width: 5vh;
    border: black;
}

.editBtn {
    padding: 3vw !important;
    color: #4ddd40 !important;
    width: 5vh;
    border: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to troubleshoot without access to the components and context but this code example might help give some cues for a direction to consider.

```css
.deleteBtn {
  padding: 32px;
  color: #e71f1f;
  border: black;
}

.editBtn {
  padding: 32px;
  color: #4ddd40;
  border: black;
}

.inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Title</h3>
  <button className="editBtn" size="small">
   Edit
   <span>icon</span>
   </button>
  <button className="deleteBtn" size="small">
   Delete
   <span>icon</span>
   </button>
  <span>Article</span>
</div>

<br/>
<br/>

<div>
  <h3 class="inline">Title</h3>
  <button className="editBtn" size="small">
   Edit
   <span>icon</span>
   </button>
  <button className="deleteBtn" size="small">
   Delete
   <span>icon</span>
   </button>
  <span>Article</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like there's no way to put buttons in the same line of title, isn't it?

Comment: @MemphisMeng Give the new updated demo a look. I think the `h3` is display block by default and it's causing it to span the wole width. It can be fixed by going inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

It just looks like there's no way to put buttons and header in the same line. Instead, I worked around by using  tag.

```
<div>
                                    <span>
                                        <strong>Title</strong>
                                        <IconButton className="editBtn" size="small">
                                            <EditIcon style={{ fontSize: 25 }}/>
                                        </IconButton>

                                        <IconButton className="deleteBtn" size="small">
                                            <DeleteIcon style={{ fontSize: 25 }}/>
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </span>
                                    
                                    <p>Article</p>
                                </div>
```